# Use more than one button in the same form

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

This is my first time using flask and HTML.
I'm trying to use the same form for searching and inserting.

```
<form action="/Paciente/ver-paciente" method="POST"> 
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name ="search" value = "search">Buscar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name ="insert" value = "insert">Insertar</button>
</form>
```

My python code:

```
@app.route('/Paciente/ver-paciente', methods=["POST"])
def ver_paciente():
  title = "Información de Paciente"
  firstname= request.form.get("inputname")
  lastname= request.form.get("inputlastname")
  celphone= request.form.get("inputcelphone")
  birthdate= request.form.get("inputbirthdate")
  address= request.form.get("inputaddress")

  if request.form["search"] == "search":
      paciente,reporte = database.select_paciente_query(firstname,lastname,celphone)
      if  not paciente or not reporte:
          error_statement = "Ese paciente no existe..."
          return render_template('Paciente.html', error_statement=error_statement)

      print(paciente)
      return render_template('ver_paciente.html', title=title, paciente=paciente, reporte=reporte)

  elif request.form["insert"] == "insert":
      validate = database.insert_paciente_query(firstname,lastname,birthdate,celphone,address)
      if validate == False:
          error_statement = "Error insertando paciente..."
          return render_template('Paciente.html', error_statement=error_statement)

      return render_template('Paciente.html', title=title)
```

The search button works fine, but the insert gives an error:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'search'
```

Comment: If the user clicks the `insert` button, then the `search` button is not present in the input at all.

Comment: Fixed it! Changed to `if "search" in request.form:` and `elif "insert" in request.form:`